# Sitefinity How to get custom user controls displayed on Preview/Live mode only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitefinity

I'm trying to inject custom MVC user controls programmatically to only display in Preview mode or published page and not appear in Edit mode. I was able to add the new user controls but I just don't see them appear in Preview. All the forums mention you should save the changes, but I don't want those controls to save in the Edit mode for users to be able to change. Has anyone tried to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the Index action method can you do something like this:

```
    using Telerik.Sitefinity.Services;
    ....

    if (SystemManager.IsDesignMode)
      return new EmptyResult();

    // do the actual stuff here for the front-end page and preview mode
    var model = xxx;
    return View("Default", model);
```